# Woocommerce Grouped product child items not showing in order by menu_order

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, product

I am using woocommerce 2.6.14 version. I have a grouped product and want to show child products by their menu_order that I set from Advance Setting of the product. But on front end products are not showing as per menu_order I set.

I searched regarding this and found this code :

```
function kia_grouped_children_args( $args ){
    echo "<pre>";print_r($args);echo "</pre>";
    $args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_children_args', 'kia_grouped_children_args' );
```

But this code is not working. If I print the arguments inside the function then it show me nothing.

I also found that this issue is with 3.0+ version but I am using 2.6.14 version.

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.